# Copying a fixed range of cells down a blank column until the last row of data in another column

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

I have a worksheet (Sheet1) with 4 columns (A:D). In column A there is more than a 1000 lines of data and column D is blank.  On Sheet2 I have a range called Indicators (B2:B11) which I need to copy into column D on Sheet1 and repeat the process in the next empty cell in column D all the way down to the last row of data in column A.  This is the code I used to copy the range into column D but I have difficulty in repeating the process all the way down as I am not sure how to use the LastRow in this context.

```
Sub FillDownIndicators()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheet3.Range("Indicators").Copy
    Sheet7.Range("D2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

In short once the range is copied into Column D (10 rows) it must be copied again in the next empty row in column D until the last row is reached in column A. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying to pastespecial the content of n cells into m cells wouldn't fill the whole wanted range

so I came up with the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillDownIndicators()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Sheet7
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
            .ClearContents
            .Resize(Sheet3.Range("Indicators").Rows.Count).Value = Sheet3.Range("Indicators").Value
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-" & Sheet3.Range("Indicators").Rows.Count & "]C"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

a more compact version of which would be:

```
Sub FillDownIndicators()
    With Sheet7.Range("D2:D" & Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        .ClearContents
        .Resize(Sheet3.Range("Indicators").Rows.Count).Value = Sheet3.Range("Indicators").Value
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-" & Sheet3.Range("Indicators").Rows.Count & "]C"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Louw, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Just use your variable `LastRow` to build that range

```
Sheet7.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: trying to pastespecial the content of n cells into m cells wouldn't fill me the whole wanted range

Comment: @HTH True `m` needs to be `n*x` where `x` is an integer number. Then it should work. • In words: If you copy 10 cells then paste space needs to be `10, 20, 30, 40, …` cells.

Comment: I think a preface/warning in the answer would be more appropriate then leaving this subject  in comments. But that's just my opinion